# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" JSON error

Tags: json, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I'm trying to use JSON and I was use PostMan to return Response
this error happent
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"}

```
    public ActionResult SendVFCode(string Phone_Number)
    {
        var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string error = "";
        var SearchData ="";

        if (Phone_Number == null)
        {
            error = "Must enter your phone number";
        }
        else if ( (db.PhoneNumbers.Select(x =>x.Id).Count() < 0)
              &&  (db.Assistant.Select(x =>x.Id).Count()) < 0)
        {
            error = "There are no data or your account is not activated";
        }
        else
        {                
            SearchData = db.PhoneNumbers.Include(x => x.Assistant)
            .Where(x => x.PhoneNumber == Phone_Number 
            && x.Assistant.IsActive == true).Select(xx =>xx.PhoneNumber).ToList().ToString();
        }

        json = new
        {
            err = error,
            ResultSearchData = SearchData
        };

        return Content(jsonSerialiser.Serialize(json));
    }
```

Comment: Remove `.ToString()` from your query

Comment: but var SearchData need to initialization
if I was type var SearchData ="";
mut add 
.Tostring()

Comment: It is initialized - its a `List<string>` but then you convert it to a `string`. Again REMOVE `.ToString()`

Comment: when I was change to List<string> SearchData; error occurre in ResultSearchData = SearchData compiler said use of unassigend local variable in SearchData

Comment: Its `var SearchData = new List<string>();` - but you do not even need it - just delete that and use `var SearchData = db.PhoneNumbers.Include(......`

Answer (score 0):

`SearchData` is not a string. Don't declare it as string and don't try to shove a string into it. It's a List (probably of type `List<string>` or whatever your Phonenumber type is).

```
var SearchData =""
```

Should be:

```
List<string> SearchData;
```

And your database call should end in `.ToList()`, not `.ToList().ToString()`.

Comment: when I was change to List<string> SearchData;
error occurre in 
 ResultSearchData = SearchData
compiler said use of unassigend local variable in SearchData

Answer (score 0):

Note that `ToList()` followed with `ToString()` returns fully-qualified name of the list instead of the list contents, hence you should use `List<string>` to hold result strings (also the list must be instantiated first before used inside `if`-block). The correct setup should be like this:

```
public ActionResult SendVFCode(string Phone_Number)
{
    var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string error = "";
    var SearchData = new List<string>(); // instantiate list of strings

    var phoneCount = db.PhoneNumbers.Select(x => x.Id).Count();
    var assistantCount = db.Assistant.Select(x => x.Id).Count();

    if (Phone_Number == null)
    {
        error = "Must enter your phone number";
    }
    else if (phoneCount < 0 && assistantCount < 0)
    {
        error = "There are no data or your account is not activated";
    }
    else
    {                
        // assign list from query results
        SearchData = db.PhoneNumbers.Include(x => x.Assistant)
        .Where(x => x.PhoneNumber == Phone_Number && x.Assistant.IsActive == true)
        .Select(xx => xx.PhoneNumber).ToList();
    }

    var json = new
    {
        err = error,
        ResultSearchData = SearchData
    };

    return Content(jsonSerialiser.Serialize(json));
}
```

Comment: good but after that query returns nothing like this
{"err":"","ResultSearchData":[]}
Although I'm sure the code is correct
and data in tables is satisfy the condetion
this is my sql code
select userid,PhoneNumber from PhoneNumbers p
join Assistants a
on a.Id =p.UserId
where a.IsActive = 'true'
and p.PhoneNumber='0945983485'

Comment: and I was write sql query like linq query returns data

Comment: Is that `ResultSearchData` (and `SearchData`) actually has results before serialization? Also check if `PhoneNumber` contains some strings, not empty whitespace.

Comment: SearchData did not returns data
the query returns "" result and I was checked PhoneNumber have not whitespace